# SetSortMode in sphinx not working with delta index

Tags: sphinx

So my sphinx.conf file contains something similar. Basically I am using delta index to make things quick.

```
source main
{
    #...

    sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre   = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id) FROM photo

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT p.id AS id, p.search AS search, COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes \
            FROM `photo` p \
            LEFT JOIN `like` li \
            ON p.id = li.photo_id \
            WHERE p.id <= ( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 ) \
            GROUP BY \
            p.id

    #...

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id=$id
}


source delta : main
{
    sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT p.id AS id, p.search AS search, COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes \
            FROM `photo` p \
            LEFT JOIN `like` li \
            ON p.id = li.photo_id \
            WHERE p.id > ( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 ) \
            GROUP BY \
            p.id
}
```

And in the php when I retrieve data I also want to have some sort of sorting methods.

```
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@relevance DESC, total_likes DESC, @id DESC');
$result = $s->Query($data['query'], "delta main");
```

Sorting was working fine when I had only `main` index. But now when I search with both indexes, results from the delta index is appended at the front. What I actually want is results from both indexes are fetched and then sorted according to preferences i.e. `@relevance DESC, total_likes DESC, @id DESC` in my case. That is `total_likes` should be given preference over `id`

Comment: Where is the index definition in config file ?

Comment: For the benefit of others looking here, this might well of been solved.... http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11186

Comment: @barryhunter thanks a lot for your help, I have now uploaded the answer. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@barryhunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65548/barryhunter) for the [solution](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11186). The solution was that in the delta index second sql_query_pre had to be overwritten.

```
sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre =
    sql_query = \
```